# when pod of k8s restart, does the file on it exists and can be read or write well?

Tags: java, kubernetes

I run java program on k8s, but it encountered OOMKilled, i want to add jvm params like

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError 
-XX:HeapDumpPath="/tmp/dump.hprof"
```

but i wonder know does the dump file exists after the pod restart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The local filesystem of a container is ephemeral and so it will be gone once the container is killed. You should use [volume mounts](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/) to write the heapdump to an external block or file storage or at least to the host's filesystem(not recommended for production) so that you can get the dump files after the container is restarted.

```
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: a-jvm-container
        image: openjdk:11.0.1-jdk-slim-sid
        command: ["java", "-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError", "-XX:HeapDumpPath=/dumps/oom.bin", "-jar", "yourapp.jar"]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: heap-dumps
          mountPath: /dumps
      volumes:
      - name: heap-dumps
        emptyDir: {}
```

Referring from docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir)

> An emptyDir volume is first created when a Pod is assigned to a Node,
>   and exists as long as that Pod is running on that node. As the name
>   says, it is initially empty. Containers in the Pod can all read and
>   write the same files in the emptyDir volume, though that volume can be
>   mounted at the same or different paths in each Container. When a Pod
>   is removed from a node for any reason, the data in the emptyDir is
>   deleted forever

Comment: blog which talks about the same issue: https://danlebrero.com/2018/11/20/how-to-do-java-jvm-heapdump-in-kubernetes/